# How to convert a jagged double array to a string and back again?

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array

I have a jagged array of doubles that I need to convert to something I can add to an xml document then turn back into the jagged array. Anyone know of a way to do this?  Thanks in advance.

```
 public double[][] Coordinates { get; set; }

 //For context this is how I'm creating the array

 //convert the geography column back in lat\long points
 for (var g = 1; g <= geography.STNumGeometries(); g++)
 {
     var geo = geography.STGeometryN(g);
     var points = new List<double[]>();
     for (var i = 1; i <= geo.STNumPoints(); i++)
     {
         var point = new double[2];
         var sp = geography.STPointN(i);
         // we can safely round the lat/long to 5 decimal places 
         // as thats 1.11m at equator, reduces data transfered to client
         point[0] = Math.Round((double) sp.Lat, 5);
         point[1] = Math.Round((double) sp.Long, 5);
         points.Add(point);
     }

     transitLineSegment.Coordinates = points.ToArray();
 }
```

Comment: What are your requirements? Should it be “XMLy”? Is one string for the whole array okay? Should it be human-readable? How much does the size of the result matter?

Comment: @svick Doesn't have to be XMLy.  I'd prefer something that is one string since it's going to be inside another xml document.  Doesn't matter if it's human-readable.  Size doesn't matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The power of linq (code modified per suggestions in comments)

```
var doubleAR = new List<List<Double>>()
{
   new List<double>(){ 12.5, 12.6, 12.7 },
   new List<double>(){ .06 },
   new List<double>(){ 1.0, 2.0 }
};

   var asXml = new XElement("Data",
                            doubleAR.Select(sList => new XElement("Doubles", sList.Select (sl => new XElement("Double", sl) )))
                           );

    Console.WriteLine ( asXml );
/* Output
<Data>
  <Doubles>
    <Double>12.5</Double>
    <Double>12.6</Double>
    <Double>12.7</Double>
  </Doubles>
  <Doubles>
    <Double>0.06</Double>
  </Doubles>
  <Doubles>
    <Double>1</Double>
    <Double>2</Double>
  </Doubles>
</Data> */

// Then back
   List<List<Double>> asDoubleArray =
         XDocument.Parse( asXml.ToString() )
                  .Descendants("Doubles")
                  .Select (eDL => eDL.Descendants("Double")
                                     .Select (dl => (double) dl))
                                      .ToList())
                  .ToList();
```

Comment: I would get rid of the whole first `Select()`. The only thing it changes is that the code won't work correctly with some culture settings (for example, on my computer it produces `<Double>12,5</Double>`). The content of an `XElement` can be a `double` and it will take care of formatting correctly.

Comment: And the same applies to your XML-parsing code: you should cast the whole element to `double` (`dl => (double)dl`), which will work independently of culture settings (as long as the XML uses decimal point).

Comment: @svick Excellent suggestions! Code modified accordingly; I got too focused on strings such that I didn't take into account culture.

Answer (score 0):

You need to serialize the object to store it as a string. heres an example: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/815813