# Convert String To Jagged Array Of Double

Tags: c#

I have String like

```
string X="[[-122.36,47.656],[-122.343,47.656]]";
```

Now I want this to convert into a jagged array of double, `double[][] y;`

What should be the better way to achieve this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert a jagged double array to a string and back again?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10954142/how-to-convert-a-jagged-double-array-to-a-string-and-back-again)

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto - not a duplicate, since the linked question is concerned with the exact opposite: existing jagged array, doesn't care about string representation. This one has a given string representation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you have there could be understood as a JSON array containing JSON arrays. Therefore, I propose treating it as JSON:

```
string X="[[-122.36,47.656],[-122.343,47.656]]";
var deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<double[][]>(X);
```

[Try it online](https://rextester.com/XPQ5857)

** JsonConvert comes from the JSON.NET library, which can be added via NuGet.